Remove the color of the touching bars in plt.bar
So i have two problems:

the density of my histogram didn't had up to 1 while setting
density = True in my code. see the following code:


plt.hist(my_data, 25, histtype = 'step', edgecolor ='skyblue', alpha = 0.7, density = True, label = '17GHz',)
plt.title('Horn 4', fontsize = 'x-large')
plt.xlabel('Percentage of zeroes in the file [%]')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 5)) # Adjust the number of x-axis ticks # start, stop, step
plt.legend()


and plot

So first, why is that so ?? is there a way to fix this ? According to this stack subject (numpy histogram cumulative density does not sum to 1), I used plt.bar which led to my second problem

I can't have the same formating with plt.bar as with np.hist... How
do I remove the edge color of the touching bars so that it looks like the above figure?



plt.bar(bins_h4_19[:-1], probability_densities_h4_19, width = np.diff(bins_h4_19), align='edge', edgecolor='skyblue',   color ='white', label = '19 GHz')
plt.bar(bins_h4_17[:-1], probability_densities_h4_17, width = np.diff(bins_h4_17), align='edge', edgecolor='purple',   color = '#FF000000', label = '17 GHz')
plt.xlabel('Percentage of zeroes in the file [%]')
plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
plt.title('Horn 4')
plt.show()



So after a lot of searching, I realised that I wanted the y axis to be the probability density that my data falls into that bins. So I calculated this manually and plotted it with plt.stairs and it worked just fine. Here is my code:
# plt.hist returns: The values of the histogram bins, The edges of the bins
hist_wd, bins_wd, _ = plt.hist(wd_column, bins = 25, alpha=0.6, edgecolor = 'b')

# add this to hide the plot
plt.close()

# Calculate the bin width
bin_width_wd = bins_wd[1] - bins_wd[0]

# Manually normalize the histogram counts to get the probability density
hist_density_wd = hist_wd / (len(wd_column))

plt.figure(figsize = (10,4))
plt.stairs(hist_density_wd, bins_wd, linewidth=2, color = 'blue'  )



The proportions across bins will sum to 1. The density is proportion divided by the bin width (proportion of samples per unit bin width). Density = (counts / total_counts) / bin_width. The part in brackets is the proportion of samples in that bin (which is I think you were thinking of), and the full equation takes the units or width into account.

To get them to sum to one:
print(
    np.sum(densities0 * bin_width0),
    np.sum(densities1 * bin_width1)
)

#result: 1.0 1.0


Reproducible example:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Data for testing
np.random.seed(2)
data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(500, 2))
data[-50:, 1] = np.random.uniform(0, 0.2, size=(50))
data[-50:, 0] = np.random.uniform(0.8, 1, size=(50))
n_bins = 25

densities0, bins0, _ = plt.hist(data[:, 0], n_bins, histtype='step',
                                edgecolor='skyblue', linewidth=3,
                                density=True, label='17GHz')

densities1, bins1, _ = plt.hist(data[:, 1], n_bins, histtype='step',
                                edgecolor='tab:brown', linewidth=3,
                                density=True, label='19GHz')
plt.legend(ncols=2)

#Formatting
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 3)
plt.xlabel('proportion of files')
plt.ylabel('density')
plt.gca().spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_bounds(0, 1)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_bounds(0, 1.75)

#Densities come to 1
bin_width0 = np.diff(bins0)[0]
bin_width1 = np.diff(bins1)[0]

print(
    np.sum(densities0 * bin_width0),
    np.sum(densities1 * bin_width1)
)


Okay so what are you saying is that the total density of my data is the sum of the height of each column times the width of each column, correct ?

Yeah that's right. The total density will come to 1 when using np.histogram(..., density=True).

But this is what I did, you can see my code above, and it clearly does not come to one. I checked it with the following code
bin_counts, _ = np.histogram(my_data, bins = 25, density = True) sum_bin_counts = np.sum(bin_counts) print(sum_bin_counts) and it adds up to 0.25

It should be: np.sum(bin_densities * bin_width), where bin_width = np.diff(bin_edges)[0], and bin_edges is from bin_densities, bin_edges = np.histogram(..., density=True) (a more complete example is available the bottom of my answer).

Your snippet would be correct only when density=False; in that case np.histogram returns the bin counts and they will sum to the total counts (and you could convert the integer counts to a proportion or percentage by dividing through by total counts).

If you're after the percentage that each bin accounts for, you'd need to do: counts, _ = np.histogram(..., density=False), and then bin_percentages = counts / counts.sum() * 100. This would give you the proportion of the data that each bin is responsible for, and bin_percentages.sum() would come to 1.0 or 100%.

Okay I see, I tested with your code (multiplying with bin width) and it adds up to one ! Thank you ! So do you think that the first plot of my question is correct regarding the y axis ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
